# How can you describe "percentage" in a sentence?

Tags: comparatives, comparisons, percentages

I need to compare two system and explain that one is faster than the other specifying the percentage, so is the following correct?

> in fact new system computes the whole dataset the 10% percent faster
>   than the old one

Thanks for your advice. 
Dom

Comment: Sounds pretty good the way that you've stated it, other than you should take out the "the" ahead of "10%" and move it ahead of "new", and put a comma after "fact".

Comment: Oops!!  Yeah, I missed that you'd doubled down on "percent".

Comment: In fact, ***the*** new system computes the whole dataset ten percent faster than the old one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the sentence is correct. If 10 percent is the quantity at hand, I'd write "10 percent" and not "10 % percent".

Comment: Yes, 10% percent is the same as 0.1% or one-tenth of one percent, which is measurable but not earth-shaking.